# Possibility of validation of required parameters?

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm developing webservices with jaxws, so I generate wsdl and xsd files from annotated java classes via wsgen. 
I'm searching for possibility of automatic validation of parameters which are marked as required via the annotation `@XmlElement(required = true)` on the server-side.

All that I found is `@SchemaValidation`. But that doesn't fit the problem.

The documentation of that class says: "Validates all request and response messages payload(`SOAP:Body`) for a WebService against the XML schema."

But clearly that doesn't include a `required` checking.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you consider using jsr-303 bean validation, it will require you to add more Annotations but it separates unmarshaling from validation which I found more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

In standard JAXB, the `required` attribute of `XmlElement` is only used when generating XML Schema documents from your code. It is not used at runtime for data validation.

If you want to perform declarative data validation, you need to use schema validation. I'm not sure why you're resisting that - it's much more powerful than any java-based constraints can be.

Comment: I'm developing webservices with jaxws. (Therefore I set only the jaxws tag.) So the wsdl and xsd files will be generated via wsgen. All that I need is that required parameters are not null.

Comment: @Michael: JAX-WS uses JAXB to perform its XML binding and validation.

Comment: Ok. So what do I have to do to get my NotNull-validation?

Comment: @Michael: Use schema validation, like I said.